# Hive field delimeter as fixed offset

Tags: hadoop, hive

Could anybody tell: is possible create hive table and separate values via fixed offset.
For example, file:
col1 col2 col3
In this case 1-4 characters will first column in table, 5-8 characters second column,8-12 characters third.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cdh-user/9xvU0RyqKPA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309700/regex-for-fixed-width-field

Answer (score 3):

I've solved similar problems this way:

Given input of newline-separated rows, fixed-offset columns,

First input the data into a table of one column, a string

Then pass through either a Java class or a Python module via streaming hadoop, that takes in one line, and returns multiple fields:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # line will have a newline on the end you don't want
    line = line.strip()
    output = []
    output.append(line[:4])
    output.append(line[4:8])
    output.append(line[8:12])
    print '\t'.join(output)
```

Your hive script will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS input_raw(line STRING);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${hiveconf:input}' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE input_raw;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS processed_data(
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING
field3 STRING);

delete FILE processing.py;

add FILE processing.py;

INSERT INTO TABLE processed_data
SELECT
TRANSFORM (line)
USING 'python processing.py'
AS(field1, field2, field3)
FROM input_raw;

DROP TABLE input_raw;
```

Answer (score 3):

you could also avoid streaming and python and all of that following your approach, but using hive substr()

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS input_raw(line STRING);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${hiveconf:input}' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE input_raw;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS processed_data(
field1 STRING,
field2 STRING
field3 STRING);

INSERT INTO TABLE processed_data
SELECT
substr(line,1,4) as field1,
substr(line,5,4) as field2,
substr(line,9,4) as field3
FROM input_raw;

DROP TABLE input_raw;
```

Comment: I wish I had seen this back when I was still on that project :)